# I need to search based on hyperlink url in SharePoint 2013

Tags: search, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have videos embedded as links in Sharepoint , these videos are not part of SharePoint farm. I need to search for these URLs and replace with different URLs. Is there any search configuration that am missing.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.
 As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
 See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sorry if it does not clarify the question , the scenario is I need to find all the anchor tags in sharepoint that match the specific URL .  I thought search would be a good approach to find these anchor tags. But when I use search I am not getting results matching the href elements , I get results based on the text matching the anchor tag but  not the hrefs. My question is that is there some configuration that am missing to search hyperlinks of anchor tags . Hope it clarifies

Answer (score 0):

I have an approach but it's a little bit tricky:

What you could do is to create a new Text managed property that maps to the `A.HREF` crawled property which is the `href` of a hyperlink. You'll have to enable the `Queryable` and `Retrieveable` settings for it (Remember to perform a FULL CRAWL after you've created a new managed property).

After the managed property is created you could perform a search using your new property in the search condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I will try and get back to you if I have more questions.